# problema al conectar mediante pdo

Tags: php, apache, pdo, xampp

estoy utilizando pdo para conectarme a una base de datos mysql, antes funcionaba perfecto, pero ahora se ha roto algo. 
Los mensajes de error que aparecen son:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\taller-poo-a\app\database\DatabaseConnector.php on line 16
```

y el otro error es:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Solo se permite un uso de cada direcci�n de socket (protocolo/direcci�n de red/puerto)
```

Aveces sale un error, aveces sale el otro, ya no entiendo nada.

La clase de la conexion es esta:

```
 class DatabaseConnector
{
    private $db_host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = 'taller-php';
    private $db_user = 'root';
    private $db_pass = '';

    private $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        try{
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", 
                                    $this->db_user, 
                                    $this->db_pass); 
            $this->connection->exec("set names utf8");
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

            }
    }

    public function getConnection(){

        if ($this->connection === null) {
            $this->connection = new self();
        }
        return $this->connection;

    }
}
```

y la clase user donde estoy usandola tiene este metodo:

```
public function getAllUsers(DatabaseConnector $connector){
    try{

        $connection = $connector->getConnection();
        $preparedQuery = $connection->prepare('select * from users');
        $preparedQuery->execute();

        $users = $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $users;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Estoy realizando la conexion como siempre, pero nose que pasa.

Comment: Verifica que todos los servicios de tu paquete XAMPP estén corriendo, si ya reiniciaste tu pc intenta reinstalar.

Comment: en el log del panel de control aparece NetStat TCP service stopped. Please restart the control panel. Returned -1073741823
he reiniciado ya varias veces el panel pero sigue mal

Comment: Intenta cambiar el puerto entrando en tu archivo Apache (httpd.conf) y dentro cambia la linea Listen 80, el 80 lo cambias por ejemplo por el puerto 81

Comment: ya solucioné el error, se me olvidó borrar una instancia del objeto usando ese metodo en la vista, como no estaba cerrada la conexión debe haber tirado el error. Era capa 8, que verguenza